# Need to extract output given below from the following data preferably in (sed or awk) :

Tags: linux, unix

```
romlogNF.102516.gz:10/25/16 03:38:32 OUT ID=123456789-1-3  <rpy><ord_sts><sess_id>102422345678</sess_id><rtn_cde>-44</rtn_cde><code_nbr>1940</code_nbr><stg_ord_nbr>0</stg_ord_nbr><inv_nbr>0</inv_nbr><prj_nbr>0</prj_nbr></ord_sts></rpy>
romlogNF.102616.gz:10/26/16 04:38:32 OUT ID=123456789-1-3  <rpy><ord_sts><sess_id>202422345945</sess_id><rtn_cde>-44</rtn_cde><code_nbr>1942</code_nbr><stg_ord_nbr>0</stg_ord_nbr><inv_nbr>0</inv_nbr><prj_nbr>0</prj_nbr></ord_sts></rpy>
```

Output to be required :

```
ID=123456789-1-3 <code_nbr>1940</code_nbr>
ID=123456789-1-3 <code_nbr>1942</code_nbr>
```

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk -v FS="[[:space:]]|<code_nbr>|</code_nbr>" '{print $4,"<code_nbr>"$7"</code_nbr>"}'
```

In the awk, the FS is for the field separators, With the pipe symbol ('|'), you can set multiple field separator. In this case I set as fields separators a space, and the tags "<code_nbr>" and "</code_nbr>".

Comment: @codeforfun Please mark it as the correct answer. Thank you